# Frida - hook native method failure on android-Q

Tags: python, android-10.0, frida

I have a sample app, which have a `int add(int a,int b)` in native library.

I use below code to hook the `add` method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import frida
import sys

package_name = "com.sample.hello"
apiname = "add"

def get_messages_from_js(message, data):
    if message['type'] == 'send':
        print(message['payload'])
    else:
        print(message)

def instrument_debugger_checks():
    hook_code = """
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "%s"), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        console.log("onEnter...");
        //send (Memory.readUtf8String (args [1]));     
    },
    onLeave: function(args) {
        console.log("onLeave...");
    }
});
"""%(apiname)
    return hook_code

process = frida.get_usb_device().attach(package_name)
script = process.create_script(instrument_debugger_checks())
script.on('message',get_messages_from_js)
script.load()
sys.stdin.read()
```

I use below command to get the function name from so:

```
$ nm -D libnative2.so |grep add

0000000000082504 T _ZNSt6__ndk114__shared_count12__add_sharedEv
0000000000082574 T _ZNSt6__ndk119__shared_weak_count10__add_weakEv
000000000008255c T _ZNSt6__ndk119__shared_weak_count12__add_sharedEv
0000000000042d8c T add
```

I have tried all these names, result is the same.

But when I run it, I got below error:

```
{'type': 'error', 'description': 'Error: expected a pointer', 'stack': 'Error: expected a pointer\n    at frida/runtime/core.js:387\n    at /script1.js:9', 'fileName': 'frida/runtime/core.js', 'lineNumber': 387, 'columnNumber': 1}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you sure the native function name is exactly `add`? How have you identified the function name?

Comment: @Robert Yes, I got multiple names but all names doesn't work, error message the same. I have updated my question.

Comment: Have you checked if `libnative2.so` has already been loaded when you execute the frida code snippet? Native libraries that interact with Android Java code are usually loaded when the class it it used in is first loaded. Therefore it may be not loaded at start-up. Check the loaded modules using `Process.enumerateModulesSync();`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like You have an issue with timing.
Try the following Frida script:

`Java.perform(function() {
    const System = Java.use("java.lang.System");
    const Runtime = Java.use("java.lang.Runtime");
    const SystemLoad_2 = System.loadLibrary.overload("java.lang.String");
    const VMStack = Java.use("dalvik.system.VMStack");

    SystemLoad_2.implementation = function(library) {
        console.log("Loading dynamic library => " + library);
        try {
            const loaded =     Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary0(VMStack.getCallingClassLoader(), library);
            if(library.includes("native2")) {
// here your hook
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName("libnative2.so", "%s"), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        console.log("onEnter...");
        //send (Memory.readUtf8String (args [1]));     
    },
    onLeave: function(args) {
        console.log("onLeave...");
    }
});


}
            return loaded;
        } catch(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    };
});`